# Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

While my bot was running while I was asleep this warning came up saying:

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 guildMembersChunk listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Now my bot is in a decent amount of servers, How do I fix this?

I looked around and saw this:

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;
```

Would this be the solution?

Comment: You need to show code - are you creating listeners for guildMembersChunk, or is it being created by the library at some point? Do you have any logs about what happened before the error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

A maximum of `10` listeners can be registered for any event `by default`. This limit can be changed for individual emitter instances using `setMaxListener()` method, and the value can also be set to `Infinity` by setting maxListeners count to `0`.
Since you have set the limit to `15` and whenever the listener's count exceeds this limit you will see the `EventEmitter memory leak detected` error. Instead of setting it to `15` listeners set it to `Infinity` and see the behavior.

**For example:**

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const emitter = new EventEmitter();

//Setting the listeners to Infinity
emitter.setMaxListeners(0);

//To validate the number of listeners listening to event you may log the below line
emitter.listenerCount('eventName');
```